# JSON: Get object by attribute

Tags: jquery, json

i have a json like this:

```
{
    "page": {
        "id": 220,
        "parentId": 196,
        "property": {
            "1": {
                "name": "h1",
                "value": "value i dont need",
            },
            "2": {
                "name": "tags",
                "value": "value i dont need",
            },
            "3": {
                "name": "description",
                "value": "value i need",
            },
}
```

**The question is:** how can i get "value i need", if the id of property ("3" in my case) is changing dynamicly?
So, i cannot just use

```
data.page.property[3].value
```

btw, i'm using jquery.

thanks!

-- edited due to misunderstanding

Comment: `data.page.property[your_variable].value` this should work

Comment: if you mean you want to get ***the third*** property (don't care/not sure about its name), you can use the `for ... in` loop in combination with a counter, if the counter reaches the value `2` (the third), then access the property and break the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its going to be a random object from some server, then only have is you have to iterate the object and compare what you need,

```
for(i in data.page.property)
{
     if(data.page.property[i].value && data.page.property[i].value === "your value")
        // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a specific value **by name** you can use a function such as the following:

```
function getValue( name ) {
    var val = '';
    $.each(data.page.property, function(k,v) { 
        if( v.name == name ) {
            val = v.value;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return val;
};

console.log( getValue( "description" ) ); //output: value i need
console.log( getValue( "tags" ) ); //output: value i dont need
console.log( getValue( "h1" ) ); //output: value i dont need
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/8D75F/1/)

Comment: i cannot use "3" because it's changing dynamicly. it can be 2 or 5 different times.

Comment: I have updated my answer and will give a demo shortly.

Comment: @Rusher, I have looked at you updated JSON. How do you decide what you need? Is it the last one, or by value `value i need`? Without clarifying that, and the fact that your requirements keep changing, you're not going to get a good answer.

Comment: by name. i thought i can do something like `data.page.property[@name='description'].value`

Comment: @Rusher, that's much clearer now; makes sense. I'll update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `property`-array until you find a `value` field. then read it

Comment: but i have many "value" fields. probably i need to find somtheing like name=description.

Comment: then iterate until you find the correct `name` field

Comment: just thought that there's something like `data.page.property[@name='description'].value` like in xslt.

Answer (score 1):

```
var prop = data.page.property
for(k in prop)
{
  if(prop[k].name == 'name you are interested')
    var v = prop[k].value || someDefaultValue; 
    // do something about v
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote this general function which can take any object/array and find objects by attribute & it's value. No matter if you provide array, object or array of objects. No matter how deep structure is etc. It will just go through everything and find all objects which have defined attribute and it's value is equal to provided value. That's what i was searching when found this answer so hopefully somone will benefit:

```js
function findObjectWithKey(obj, key, value, results) {
  if (obj && typeof obj === "object" && Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach((_obj) => {
      results = findObjectWithKey(_obj, key, value, results);
    });
  } else if (obj && typeof obj === "object" && Object.keys(obj)?.length > 0) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((_objKey) => {
      if (_objKey === key && obj[_objKey] === value) {
        results.push(obj);
      }
      results = findObjectWithKey(obj[_objKey], key, value, results);
    });
  }
  return results;
}
```

Use:

`const foundObjects = findObjectWithKey({some:{structure: false}}, 'structure', false, []);`

Return: `[{"structure":false}]`;

Answer (score 0):

*Pure Javascript Code*

```
for (var k in json.page.property) {
    var o = json.page.property[k];
    if (o.value) alert(o.value); //Make sure it only alerts if there is value
}
```

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/pXH6t/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope the value you need is of the last member of the property object,

```
var len = Object.keys(json.page.property).length;
var myValue =json.page.property[len].value ;
console.log(myValue); // prints "value i need"
```